# How to call the formatMessage() to load the messages from the .json files

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I'm trying to call the formatMessage() API directly outside the comp w/o using the standard `<FormattedMessage../>` component.

```
const locale = 'en';
const messages= defineMessages({
    greeting: {
        id: 'app.greeting',
        message:"some message",
        defaultMessage: 'Hello,all',
        description: 'Greeting to welcome the user to the app',
    }
});
const { intl } = new IntlProvider({locale, messages}).getChildContext();
export function someFunc(key, values) {
   return intl.formatMessage({id:'greeting'});
}
```

well the above is static messages defined locally, however I have a translation files, en.json and ja.json globally stored that I would like to load the messages from.
How can I do that using the defineMessages, so that when I call the formatMessage() I should be able to see the messages from the resp files depending on the locale selected...
ideas appreciated!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the format of your `.json` files, but you can reformat them (if needed) so each key in them has at least `id` and `defaultMessage` ([details](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#definemessages)) and pass to `defineMessages()` function.

```
import enMessages from 'path/to/en.json'
import jaMessages from 'path/to/ja.json'
const localeMessages = locale === 'en' ? enMessages : jaMessages

const messages= defineMessages(localeMessages);

...
const { intl } = new IntlProvider({locale, messages}).getChildContext();
intl.formatMessage({id:'greeting'});
```

Answer (score 1):

If using the `react-router` npm package, you can set the `IntlProvider` component (from the `react-intl` npm package) as the main route within your route definitions. This means that all the translations are passed down as props to your components, i.e. you could access a particular message with `this.props.messages.myMessage`:

```
import { IntlProvider, addLocaleData } from 'react-intl';
import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';

addLocaleData(en);
let locale = 'en-GB';
const messages = require("./i18n/" + locale + ".i18n.json");
const renderRoutes = ({ locale, messages }) => (
    <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
    ...
    </IntlProvider>
);
ReactDom.render((renderRoutes({ locale, messages })), this.container);
```